# What common database is used with ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

I know PHP and how to use MySQL with it but now I am moving onto ASP but which common database is used with ASP (ie. the equivalent to MySQL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it's [Microsoft SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server).

If you want a free alternative you could try with [Microsoft SQL Server Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express), which is a scaled down version.

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx) you can find more informations about the different versions.

Comment: No, it's not. However you could try with the scaled down version [Microsoft SQL Server Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) which is free, but beware of possible licensing issues, I do not know if you can or can't use it in production environments.

Comment: Express Edition will do 10GB now, and it's always handled a LOT more than just two or three connections.

Comment: @Paul - the 2nd part of your comment is just not true.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft SQL Server.

This is commonly known as `WISA` (Windows, IIS, SQL Server, ASP) stack.

Comment: It starts with "Microsoft", that should give you a clue about whether it's free.

Comment: @ITg: There is a free version, `SQL Server Express`, but it has some limitations. `IIS` and `ASP` only ship with certain versions of `Windows` which are not free. `ASP` and `ASP.NET` with appropriate `OLEDB` providers / connectors allow you to use any database including `MySQL`. `Mono project` implementation of `ASP.NET` allows you to build a completely free `ASP.NET` stack.

Answer (score 2):

It is Sql Server (Express editions are free) but you shouldn't let this be your only deciding factor. Besides, it doesn't really matter. The db is the back end, unseen by your clients, and you can connect to many, many types of DBs from ASP just as well as to Sql Server.

Your main consideration should be features, scalability etc. For the sake of picking up this dev stack quickly I would suggest sticking with MySql for you. That would be one less rather large piece of technology to learn!

Also: Are you moving onto ASP (classic) or ASP.NET? If it is ASP I would recommend that you reconsider and choose a more modern web development methodology such as ASP.NET MVC or Silverlight. I think that you will find ASP.NET MVC to your liking. In some ways it feels like ASP or PHP of old but with much more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

[MS SQL server](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/) is commonly used with ASP (Classic and .NET). There are many different versions of SQL (SQL Express, Standard Edition, Enterprise etc)